# How to hot deploy xml resources onto websphere?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jvm, ejb, websphere

I need to be able to modify an xml file my EJB uses as a resource and subsequently update the deployed resource on a websphere app server. The JVM can not be restarted. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the resource is included in the application.  If so, then yes, you can redeploy the application while the server is running, which will restart the application.  There is no supported way to update a file in the application without redeploying the application.